# SAS: Ceil a time format variable

Tags: time, sas, ceil

Is it possible to use the command `ceil` on a time format variable such as 09:31:23? I would like to use `ceil` to have 09:32:00. I tried to use something similar to `round(time,'0:01:00'T)` but I want to use `ceil` since I don't want to round. Use the `round` will give me `09:31:00`. 
I tried to use `ceil` instead of `round` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since SAS time is actually a number of seconds since midnight, CEIL will give you start of next second.
To get start of next minute, use INTNX function.

```
data _null_;
    t='09:31:23.12'T;
    nextsecond=ceil(t);
    nextminute=intnx('minute', t, 1, 'BEGINNING');
    put t= time12.2 nextsecond= time12.2  nextminute= time12.2;
run;

LOG:   t=9:31:23.12 nextsecond=9:31:24.00 nextminute=9:32:00.00
```

Comment: Superb! I completely forgotten about the powerful command intnx! Thanks for the insight! Would you know how to ceil/intnx all time variables `09:31:23 09:33:33 09:38:56` to all equal `09:40:00`?

Comment: AH Nevermind! I can do the following: `nextminute=intnx('minute10', t, 1, 'BEGINNING');`