# Converting SAS IFN(), HOUR() and MINUTE() to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sas

```
(hour(date_column ) * 4)
+ ifn(minute(date_column ) = 0, 0
     , ifn(minute(date_column ) <= 15, 1
          , ifn(minute(date_column ) <= 30, 2
               , ifn(minute(date_column ) <= 45, 3, 4))))
 as date_no
```

What are the equivalents of these functions in PostgreSQL?

I am trying to extract value based on 15 mins interval in an hour.

Comment: What exactly does the code do? Can you please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. (Please [edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Are you just asking how to convert IFN() function calls into standard SQL syntax, such as CASE clause?

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you explained your goal and current logic in a bit more detail, but for now it looks like this would suffice:

```sql
select extract('hours' from date_column) * 4 
    + ceil(extract('minutes' from date_column) / 15) as date_no
from your_table;
```

1. [`extract()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) is used in PostgreSQL for the same thing [`hour()`](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/vdmmlcdc/8.11/ds2ref/p0z9mn2fuysh53n1ce9e64k6iv5h.htm) and [`minute()`](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/vdmmlcdc/8.11/ds2ref/n1grykca5tylsvn15u343zijq1lg.htm) are in SAS.
2. You can use [`CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) the exact same way you would [in SAS](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/sqlproc/n0a85s0ijz65irn1h3jtariooea5.htm) but there's no [IFN()](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/proccas/n1v6aoomm10yxnn1mf4407trgk90.htm) counterpart.
3. [`CEIL()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE) works the same in [both](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/proccas/p1rbrf4vv6531fn1i7j2garo4j2o.htm), so you could also shorten your SAS version replacing all the `IFN`'s.
4. You're effectively binning date/times, so you could look into [`date_bin()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-BIN). Similar effect can probably be achieved in SAS through the use of [`INTNX()`](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.4/lefunctionsref/p10v3sa3i4kfxfn1sovhi5xzxh8n.htm) or plain [`ROUND()`](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/vdmmlcdc/8.11/ds2ref/n004b7w2f8e0umn1etv4m2nsfimk.htm) ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334954/sas-ceil-a-time-format-variable), [2](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/How-can-I-round-time-using-SAS/td-p/358150)).

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/QTrF30S5)